# Pygame Mixer module not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, raspberry-pi, python-module

I am trying to use Pygame Mixer to play a sound from an mp3 file. When I do so, I get this error:

```
NotImplementedError: mixer module not available (ImportError: libSDL2_mixer-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

This happens when whenever I am calling `mixer.init()`

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://github.com/snipsco/snipsmanager/issues/35) but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated. Thank You in advance!

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have the `libsdl2-mixer` package installed?  Try: `dpkg -l | grep libsdl2-mixer`

Comment: @Kingsley how do I check? `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install libsdl2-mixer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsdl2-mixer`

Comment: Also try: `apt-cache search libsdl2` to get a list of available packages.  Maybe it needs a version-number too.  I don't have a rPi here right now to test, but *maybe* the package name is `libsdl2-mixer-2.0`.

Comment: @Kingsley I found these two installed that were related to mixer: `libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 - Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 2, libraries
libsdl2-mixer-dev - Mixer library for Simple DirectMedia Layer 2, development files`

Comment: That worked, Thanks!